# Cast single character QString to Char

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring

I'm a little stuck with an old assignment while doing exam revision. I'm reading in 4 values from console, but in a single line. They're GPS Coordinates, for example the input could be `25 46 3 S`. I am using the following code to read in the values:

```
cout << "Latitude: ";
latitudeLine = cin.readLine();

QStringList args = latitudeLine.split(" ");
degrees = args[0].toInt();
minutes = args[1].toInt();
seconds = args[2].toInt();
cardinalDirection = args[3];
```

latitudeLine is a QString. Degrees, minutes and seconds are integers and cardinalDirection is a char. I cannot change these as they're given to me in a UML diagram in the question. Everything is wokring okay, except that in the last line I'm assigning a QString to a char variable which doesn't work. I have looked around the net and all I've found is to convert a long QString to a char*, but this gives me an error saying I need a char and not char*. This will always be a single character, is there any simple way of casting the QString to a char?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the index operator like this: `args[3][0].toAscii()`?
The index operator will return the `QChar` at position 0 and [QChar::toAscii](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#toAscii) will return the `char` inside the `QChar`.

Note: Don't forget to check if `args[3]` is not empty otherwise the index operator will crash the application.

**EDIT:**
As `@hyde` said, use `QString::toLatin1` instead of `QString::toAscii`.

Comment: I'm still new to Qt, so I'm not familiar with all the little functions it offers. I try read through documentation when I can though.

Your first answer returned a QChar rather than a char, but I had no idea of the toAscii() function! Thank you so much. Worked 100%

Comment: @nickcorin Do not use `toAscii()`, it does not really do what the name says (read the docs for details) so it will just confuse people, and has been removed from Qt5. Usually, you should use `toLatin1()` instead.